# Bash: what is the difference between `cp fileA fileB` and `cp -- fileA fileB`

Tags: shell-script, shell, command-line

What is the difference between `cp fileA fileB` and `cp -- fileA fileB` in Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--` specifies the end of options.  In your specific example this shouldn't make a difference but if you were using filename globbing such as: `cp * fileB` to find a file and you had a file in your directory named `-R` for example your command could potentially be:

```
cp -R dirA fileB
```

Which obviously wouldn't be the desired outcome.  This is especially important when using commands like `rm`.